# Which WAV format to use for System.Speech?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, wav

While converting mp3 files to .wav format for use in system.speech by using the setInputToWavFile method, i noticed that i can choose signed 16 bit PCM or 32 bit float PCM.
Which of the two will work better with System.speech?

Comment: I am interested to know also about this. Did you try having the 2 formats of wav files and tested them? Do you get an error if you try using 32 bit float PCM format?

Comment: Yup, 32 Bit float PCM is not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, 32 bit float PCM is not supported at all.